# Variables values do not extract for Task group parameters in VSTS

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As per the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=vsts, When creating task group from tasks so it automatically extracts variables from tasks and converted into parameters, and variables values will be the parameters default value.

But it is not working in my case. When I am trying to create it using variables `$(MyVariable)`, variables values do not extract and become a default value for task group parameters.

In fact, I have to add the default value for the parameters, which will pass to task arguments where actually defined variables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what the problem is? I don't understand what you're asking. Screenshots may be useful in this case.

Comment: Do you specify the value for that variable in release definition? Could you provide the detail log here? (Add system.debug variable with true value)

Comment: Fired an issue https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9482